# How to dissalow nginx serving static files when subdomain isn't recognized by django?

Tags: django, nginx, multi-tenant, saas, wildcard-subdomain

I have a configuration with statics file served by nginx at location /static and django (though gunicorn) on / location.
My app in multitenant and i use subdomain for identifying tenant.
Nginx servername is:
server_name ~^(.*.)?my-domain.loc$;
My django is sending 404 error when accessing / on a subdomain that don't exist. I want to not give response to (ever django or static) when django response is 404 for a subdomain.

any idea ?

Comment: I'm guessing you have a `/static` location configured inside the `server` block in your nginx configuration. That's a big mistake because for every subdomain, the static files will load again. Not good. Create a separate `server` block in your nginx config especially for serving static files, like `static.my-domain.com`.

Comment: Hi, it's not really a problem because access from the same users will not occur much. Any idea on my primary question ?

Comment: If you serve static files from a dedicated subdomain, that would also solve your issue. Other than that, I have no suggestions.

Comment: Mmmm' forgot to say: "/" is also "static" it's a Vue app.

Comment: Not sure I understand fully,  If django responds 404 on a subdomain you don't want the client to see a 404 page, is that right? If so, what do you want to happen?